# Number of binary operations on $S$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given a set S, a function $f : S \times S \to S$ is called a binary operation on $S$. If $S$ is a  finite set, then how many different binary operations on S are possible?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: this is equivalent to the following for $|S|=8$. If you have an $8 \times 8$ chessboard (grid), how many different ways can you fill in the squares of the board so that each square has some number between $1$ and $8$ inclusive? Do you see why this is the same as your question?